# Proof of algebraically closedness of $\mathbb{C}$ by using triangle inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

There is a step in the proof of the algebraically closedness of $\mathbb{C}$ concerning the triangle inequality, which I do not really understand. Can someone clarify this to me? Thanks!

$\textbf{Statement}$: Let $P: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} : z \mapsto P(y)= \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{k}z^{k}$ be a polynomial of degree $n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}$ with coefficients $a_{k} \in \mathbb{C}$. Then there exists a $z_{0} \in \mathbb{C}$ so that $P(z_{0})=0$.

$\textbf{Proof}$: Without restriction of generality, we can take $a_{n}=1$. Let $m= \inf \{ |P(z)|$ where $z \in \mathbb{C} \}$. Take $r \in \mathbb{R}_{0}$. For every $z \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|z|=r$, it holds that $|P(z)| \geq r^{n}(1- \frac{|a_{n-1}|}{r} -\frac{|a_{n-2}|}{r^{2}}-...-\frac{|a_{1}|}{r^{n-1}}-\frac{|a_{0}|}{r^{n}} )$ because of the triangle inequality.

Now it is the last statement that I do not get, because so far I have only been able to get to $|P(z)| \leq r^{n}(1+\frac{|a_{n-1}|}{r}+\frac{|a_{n-2}|}{r^{2}}+...+\frac{|a_{0}|}{r^{n}})$.

Answer (score 5):

It follows from the triangle inequality that $|z-w|\geqslant|z|-|w|$. So\begin{align*}\bigl|P(z)\bigr|&=|z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0|\\&=|z^n-(-a_{n-1}z^{n-1}-\cdots-a_0)|\\&\geqslant|z|^n-|a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0|\\&\geqslant|z|^n-|a_{n-1}||z|^{n-1}-\cdots-|a_0|\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you. That explains it.